# Histogram of multiple dataset with different dimension in Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I can plot multiple plots with a same dimension in a histogram

```
x = rand(1000,3);
hist(x);
```

[image]

But I could not plot multiple plots with a different dimension.

```
x1 = rand(1100,1);
x2 = rand(1000,1);
x3 = rand(900,1);
x = [x1 x2 x3]
hist(x)
```

I get the following error

```
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Please someone point me to right direction to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

### Triple Bar Histogram (3 datasets)

You can use the `histogram()` function and retrieve the `.binCounts` of each histogram and concatenate them in a fashion that gives a 10 by 3 array. By calling `bar()` on this 10 by 3 array you'll get a similar binning graph that shows the histogram of 3 datasets with the bins shown as triple bars. Also a good idea to use the `histogram()` function as the use of `hist()` is no longer recommended by MATLAB.

[image: Triple Bar Histogram]

```
x1 = rand(1100,1);
x2 = rand(1000,1);
x3 = rand(900,1);

h1 = histogram(x1);
Counts_1 = h1.BinCounts;
h2 = histogram(x2);
Counts_2 = h2.BinCounts;
h3 = histogram(x3);
Counts_3 = h3.BinCounts;

Bin_Edges = h3.BinEdges;
Bin_Width = h3.BinWidth;
Bin_Centres = Bin_Edges(1:end-1) + Bin_Width/2;

Counts = [Counts_1.' Counts_2.' Counts_3.'];
bar(Counts);
title("Triple Bar Histogram");
xlabel("Bin Centres"); ylabel("Count");
set(gca,'xticklabel',Bin_Centres);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried all four ways; they are creating a array with single column or single row. Which does give me a histogram but it is mix of all three variables i.e. x1, x2 and x3. I could not distinguish between the data

Comment: You're looking for 3 distinct histograms? Do you need them on separate subplots?

Comment: I added the plot to the original post, I'm looking for something similar

Comment: Added the code to do that on the top of my answer.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for your answer. I was thinking about pad the smaller matrices with some negative value and then just don't show that value on the plot. But your solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Well the problem is indeed that you cant add non size matching vars.

Here is a patch work for you:
the magic is the Nan variable that make your code match

```
% its bad habits but:
x1 = rand(1100,1);
x2 = rand(1000,1);
x3 = rand(900,1);

% make em' all the same size
max_size = max([length(x1),length(x2),length(x3)]);

% add in the ending nan 
x1 = [x1; nan(max_size-length(x1), 1)];
x2 = [x2; nan(max_size-length(x2), 1)];
x3 = [x3; nan(max_size-length(x3), 1)];

% plot em' bad
x = [x1 x2 x3];
figure;
hist(x)
```

Its working great now! (but you know its a bit of a Frankenstein masterpiece :-)

Comment: Awesome, nice use of using `NaN` (not a number) term.

Comment: Great ! I could not have figure out the use of NaN this way.

Comment: @user158881 If you don't mind me asking why you mentioned that "% its bad habits but:". I'm MATLAB newbie, so could not figure out the reason behind it.

Comment: just take cation. if you have major differences between the sizes of the different Vars you may lose  one of the histograms.
sometimes its helpful  to normalize the plot using ("normalization" , "distribution") in the histogram plot

Comment: because NaN is a tricky friend. for example if you plot a line and the data have some NaNs around it will "break" you line instead of ignoring the values (that's what I expected and was proved wrong). anyway always check what MATLAB do with your NaNs. I prefer to avoid em but they are useful at times.